# Equivalent condition for $V\subset X$ to be a neighborhood in the inductive topology on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $\{X_i\}$ a family of topologcial vector space(equipped with topology $\mathcal{T_i}$)

let $X = \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty X_i$ equipped with inductive topology w.r.t $\{(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i,I_i)\}$(the finest topology which makes $I_i:X_i \to X$ continuous where $I_i$ is the identity map into)

Prove if for each $i$ we have $V\bigcap X_i$ is neighborhood near 0 in topological vector space $X_i$

Then $V$ is a neighborhood near 0 in topological space $X$

Comment: What do you mean by a "neighborhood near $0$"?

Comment: @azif00 Sorry I don't really know the meaning of it,I try to understand it as a open set around the 0 in the given topology. Hence I try to prove that each point in the "neighborhood",exist a basis element contains in it" ,0 is the element in the topological vector space

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the $X_i$'s are topological *vector* spaces.

Comment: @azif00 It seems not depend on the TVS ,topological structure is enough?

Comment: We need $V\subset X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking comes down to the following result.  It has nothing to do with topological vector spaces.

**Proposition**: Let $\mathcal T$ be the inductive topology on $X$ coming from the spaces $(X_i, \mathcal T_i)$, and let $\mathcal T'$ be the topology on $X$ given by the condition that $V \subseteq X$ is open if and only if $V \cap X_i$ is open in $X_i$ for each $i$.  Then $\mathcal T = \mathcal T'$.

Proof: By definition, $\mathcal T$ is the largest topology on $X$ for which each inclusion $X_i \subset X$ is continuous.  In other words, if $\mathcal T''$ is a topology on $X$ for which each inclusion $X_i \rightarrow X$ is continuous, then $\mathcal T'' \subseteq \mathcal T$.  Since each inclusion $X_i \rightarrow X$ is clearly continuous for $\mathcal T'$, we have $\mathcal T' \subseteq \mathcal T$.

On the other hand, if $V \subseteq X$ belongs to $\mathcal T$, then each $V \cap X_i$ is open in $X_i$, and hence $V \in \mathcal T'$.  Thus $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal T'$.

Comment: thanks for your clear proof.

Comment: Can you recommend some reference book?

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not sure, I never read any books on topology or topological vector spaces besides Munkres